# Dynamically generate sql query based on

Tags: c#, sql

I need to populate a gridview based on the values entered or selected from dropdownlist or textboxes. A user might not mention all the criterias.I'm looking for a solution to dynamically generate database query according to the user's choices.

Comment: `if` statements are usually good for modifying values based on conditions.

Comment: Following are the criterias-

Above or equal to percent - textbox
above or equal to cgpa - textbox
experience(in months) - textbox
Industry- dropdownlist
Specialization - dropdown
Highest degree - dropdown
College - dropdown
Location - dropdown

Comment: @SupriyaParate: You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow.  This is not a free coding service which accepts requirements and emits code for you.  We're happy to help with any code you're writing by answering questions about errors or unexpected behavior.  But you have to actually put in *some* effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you will need to change code according to your conditions.

```
            StringBuilder sqlQuery;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword; ");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string join = "";
            // textboxes
            if (TextBox_percentage.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                sqlQuery.Append(join+" [percentage_column]>=@percentage");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@percentage", TextBox_percentage.Text);
                join = " and ";

            }
            if (TextBox_cgpa.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [cgpa_column]>=@cgpascore");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cgpascore", TextBox_cgpa.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            if (TextBox_experience.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [experience_column]=@experience");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@experience", TextBox_experience.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            // dropdowns, 'Default value'? Text/Value?
            if (dropdown_Industry.SelectedItem.Text != "Default Value")
            {

                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [Industry_column]=@Industry");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Industry", dropdown_Industry.SelectedItem.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            if (dropdown_Specialization.SelectedItem.Text != "Default Value")
            {

                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [Specialization _column]=@Specialization ");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specialization ", dropdown_Specialization.SelectedItem.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            if (dropdown_Highest_degree.SelectedItem.Text != "Default Value")
            {

                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [Highest_degree_column]=@Highest_degree");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Highest_degree", dropdown_Highest_degree.SelectedItem.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            if (dropdown_College.SelectedItem.Text != "Default Value")
            {

                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [College_column]=@College");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@College", dropdown_College.SelectedItem.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }
            if (dropdown_Location.SelectedItem.Text != "Default Value")
            {

                sqlQuery.Append(join + " [Location_column]=@Location");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", dropdown_Location.SelectedItem.Text);
                join = " and ";
            }

            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table where " + sqlQuery.ToString();
            con.Open(); // try-catch-finally
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            gridView.DataSource = dt;
            gridView.DataBind();
```